# Retrieve all elements in an array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How can I assign an array to a variable. I am able to return the documents that I want but not able to specifically get all the elements in the array inside a particular field. This field is called 'likes.'

My query to filter documents I want:

```
Posts.find({}, {owner: Meteor.user()})
```

I would like to retrieve all the elements inside an array field called 'likes' from the Posts collection. (Each element in the 'likes' field is an object ID)

I tried with various operators such as $all and $in of the 'likes' field and tested within console.log, but I cant manage to get the Ids. According to the mongo docs, I need to specify an element within the operator but I don't want that. I simply want anything that is inside.

```
var likers = Posts.find({}, {owner: Meteor.user()}, {likes: {$in: [] }})
```

Basically, Im trying to retrieve all the elements from the 'likes' field so I can make another query to return results.

I am running meteor 0.9+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```js
var myPosts = Posts.find(
  {owner: Meteor.user()},
  {fields: {likes: 1}}
).fetch()

var myLikes = _.chain(myPosts)
  .pluck('likes')
  .flatten()
  .uniq()
  .value();
```

First we fetch all of the posts where the current user is the owner. Each post will contain an `_id` and a `likes` array. Next we extract all of the likes by:

1. Plucking out each `likes` from each document. This gets us an array of arrays.
2. Flatten the array of arrays into a single array of likes.
3. Run `uniq` so we have only the unique likes (not necessary but could be an optimization).

You can then use `myLikes` in a subsequent query. For example:

```js
Likes.find({_id: {$in: myLikes}})
```

---

Here is some test data in case `myPosts` is empty:

```js
var myPosts = [
  {_id: 1, likes: [1, 2, 3]},
  {_id: 2, likes: [2, 3, 4]},
  {_id: 3, likes: [4, 5, 6]}
];
```

In this case `myLikes` will be: `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]`

Comment: Hi David, I have tried this. After putting the myLikes variable into the console.log and into another query, there is no value returned.

Comment: It may be that `myPosts` is an empty array for you because the documents don't exist or they were not published. Assuming I got the right data structure, the `myLikes` code is correct. I added some test data to the bottom of my answer to verify.

Comment: Thank you, so. freakin'. much.

Comment: @DavidWeldon THANKS! I have been searching for this for months!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which fields you want your cursor to contain, so you can limit it to the `likes` field:

```
var allLikes = Posts.find({
  owner: Meteor.user()
}, {
  fields: {likes: 1},
}).fetch();
```

This will give you an array of all posts, where each post contain only the `likes` array:

```
[{
  likes: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
}, {
  likes: ['D', 'E'],
}];
```

etc. Now, I understand you want a single array with all the objectIDs listed there. For this you can transform the array with underscore. There are numerous ways to obtain the result, for example:

```
var likes = _.reduce(allLikes, function(memo, post) {
  return memo.concat(post.likes);
}, []);
```

Comment: Each post will only have one array. Inside it is a list of object ids. 
So the underscore method is not necessary but thanks for pointing it out I can keep in mind for future.

From a single array such as the one you wrote  ['A', 'B', 'C'] I would like this in a variable AllLikes. Then, query another collection  Forms.find({_id: allLikes});

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to retrieve all the values inside the array of the 'likes' field. Then use these values to query another collection.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised, in the Posts.find query, I had to insert an empty criteria for it to work. So the change resulted to the following.

```
var myPosts = Posts.find(
{},
{owner: Meteor.user()},
{fields: {likes: 1}}
).fetch()
```

Either way, I could not have come to this result without your input so plus one for you David!